# Can I perform simple math addition/subtraction in a button's text area in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am currently using Python and Kivy to create a simple app. I currently have a button where I want the button's text show the the sum of two other button's text. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

I know text: only accepts strings, so I've tried using `int()` and `str()` hoping to convert the texts into something I can run. But the error I ran into is

> TypeError: 'kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy' object is not callable

```py
#abilityscore.kv
<AbilityScore@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size: 50, 50
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: 153, 102, 0, 1

<BlankButton@Button>:
    size: 50, 50
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: 153, 102, 0, 0

<CalcGridLayout>:
    cols: 7
    rows: 7
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    AbilityScore:
        id: str
        text: "8"
    AbilityScore:
        id: strmod
        text: "1"
    AbilityScore:
        text: str.text + strmod.text
```

With the current code of using

```py
text: str.text + strmod.text
```

the result I get is the button showing 81, when I was hopping it being 9. as mentioned before I also tried

```py
str(int(str.text) + int(strmod.text))
```

but I got the "TypeError: 'kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy' object is not callable" error.
my hopes it to find a way so that I have

```py
   AbilityScore:
        id: str
        text: "8"
   AbilityScore:
        id: strmod
        text: "1"
   AbilityScore:
        text: <some code here>
```

where `<some code here>` returns the result of 9 being the sum of `str.text` and `strmod.text`.

Comment: can you show more code? Like where the filenames and where the variables are created / referenced. Looks like the variable is garbage collected before you reference it. 

Comment: I think the `id` being `str` causes the problem

Answer (score 1):

I you have a close look onto `str(int(str.text) + int(strmod.text))`, you'll see

**`str`**`(int(`**`str`**`.text) + int(strmod.text))`

Once you name an object `str` then you try to call the builtin function `str`. Python doesn't see the function any more, because it's shadowed by the same-name object in the inner scope. I think that's what the error message tells you:

> TypeError: 'kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy' object is not callable

#### Conclusion

So, in short, it should be possible if you avoid name clashes: <sup>*)</sup>

```
    AbilityScore:
        id: a_str
        text: "8"
    AbilityScore:
        id: b_str
        text: "1"
    AbilityScore:
        text: str(int(a_str.text) + int(b_str.text))
```

---

<sup>*)</sup>
 You should keep in mind that strings *can fail* to be evaluated to numbers. In the given case this seem not to be an issue, because the `text` values are provided by literals. If the values are produced at run time, you have to deal with non-numerical inputs, for instance in the way [shown by PalimPalim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57802605/2932052).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You could do something like

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class CalcButton(Button):

    @staticmethod
    def to_num(s):
        try:
            float(s)
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            return 0

kv_str = Builder.load_string(""" BoxLayout:
    TextInput:
        id: t1
    TextInput:
        id: t2
    CalcButton:
        text: str(self.to_num(t1.text) + self.to_num(t2.text))

""")

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv_str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

You can make it pure kv if you import the function to_num into the kv file and do not get it via the class. See https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#special-syntax

Comment: ... but if `str.text + strmod.text` gives `81`, shouldn't we be able to do it inline?

Comment: is your comment addressed? sorry did not see you already posted an answer.

Comment: Sorry, only now I saw your question. I'd like to ask you, if you are aware of this detail of the question that an assignment via `text: str.text + strmod.text` seemed to work technically (since the `text` property of both, `str` and `strmod`, is a string, a concatenation is carried out). Your answer shows a working example, but maybe the static method `to_num` isn't needed at all.

Comment: it did not work for me since int('') throws an error, hence I validate first if the string can be converted to a number.

Comment: I absolutely see your point. Besides the trivial `''`, some other conversion errors have to be caught. On the other hand: why did you switch from `int` to `float`?